# Example use cases for induction-recursion

Tags: dependent-type, agda

I know of only two uses of [induction-recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction-recursion):

1. Encoding universes as a type, [as shown in the Agda docs for recursion](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.3/language/mutual-recursion.html)
2. Encoding [Finite sets](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/projects/utgp/school/conor.pdf) as shown in Conor Mc'Bride's "datatypes of datatypes", Chapter 6, Induction-Recursion. I don't understand the point of this example, so I feel like I'm missing something.

I'd like answers to be examples of where induction-recursion is used. To quote Halmos:

> A good stack of examples, as large as possible, is indispensable for a
> thorough understanding of any concept,and when I want to learn something new,
> I make it my first job to build one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is [one article](http://spire-lang.org/blog/2014/08/04/inductive-recursive-descriptions) that discussed induction-recursion. Here's their code:

```
  data Lang : Set
  ⟦_⟧ : Lang → Set

  data Lang where
    Zero One Two : Lang
    Pair Fun Tree : (A : Lang) (B : ⟦ A ⟧ → Lang) → Lang

  ⟦ Zero ⟧ = ⊥
  ⟦ One ⟧ = ⊤
  ⟦ Two ⟧ = Bool
  ⟦ Pair A B ⟧ = Σ ⟦ A ⟧ λ a → ⟦ B a ⟧
  ⟦ Fun A B ⟧ = (a : ⟦ A ⟧) → ⟦ B a ⟧
  ⟦ Tree A B ⟧ = W ⟦ A ⟧ λ a → ⟦ B a ⟧
```

There is a related feature in Agda called [interleaved mutual definition](https://github.com/agda/agda/issues/2858) which is an even stronger variant of induction-recursion. You can look at their examples.

Here is one indirect example (which is actually induction-induction): the definition of a dependent type theory. The definitions of context, type, and term are mutually recursive as terms are only defined in a context (so the definition of term requires context), while context contains types, and in a dependent type systems types are just terms. So here we have an inductive-inductive definition if term and context are defined as inductive types. This is similar to induction-recursion to some extent.